# Hibernate Generate Tables From Entities Doesn't Work

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jboss

I'm having trouble generating tables from entities. I'm using Eclipse Photon on Mac OSX, I have successfully established a connection with my local PostgreSQL database and successfully tested the correct ping.

Now, the problem is that when I click on "JPA Tools -> Generate Tables From Entities" Eclipse does nothing. No such error message, no such signal of any kind.

I have already mapped my entities, I attach some example below.

**AccessDataEntity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "access_data")
public class AccessDataEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "password", length = 15)
    private String password;

    @OneToOne
    private PersonalInformationEntity personalInformation;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public PersonalInformationEntity getPersonalInformation() {
        return personalInformation;
    }

    public void setPersonalInformation(PersonalInformationEntity personalInformation) {
        this.personalInformation = personalInformation;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

}
```

**PersonalInformationEntity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "personal_information")
public class PersonalInformationEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 30)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname", length = 30)
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "email", length = 20)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "date_of_birth")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "personalInformation", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private AccountEntity account;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personalInformation", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<PersonalGoalEntity> personalGoals;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "personalInformation", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private AccessDataEntity accessData;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    public AccountEntity getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(AccountEntity account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    public List<PersonalGoalEntity> getPersonalGoals() {
        return personalGoals;
    }

    public void setPersonalGoals(List<PersonalGoalEntity> personalGoals) {
        this.personalGoals = personalGoals;
    }

}
```

I also have configured my **persistence.xml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="aster.jpa">
        <class>it.manuelgozzi.aster.jpa.entity.AccessDataEntity</class>
        <class>it.manuelgozzi.aster.jpa.entity.AccountEntity</class>
        <class>it.manuelgozzi.aster.jpa.entity.MovementEntity</class>
        <class>it.manuelgozzi.aster.jpa.entity.MovementGroupEntity</class>
        <class>it.manuelgozzi.aster.jpa.entity.PersonalGoalEntity</class>
        <class>it.manuelgozzi.aster.jpa.entity.PersonalInformationEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:3306/aster"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="1234"/> -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:3306/aster"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1234"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

What am I missing? I tested the connection with database and it seems to be ok, no such errors on testing ping. I don't understand why I don't see anything.

I set up my connection profile aiming to **Hibernate JPA 2.1**.

Comment: Since you have `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop` the tables would be created on application startup. Have you tried this?

Comment: I've finally made it. My bad, I didn't added hibernate dependencies in pom and then Eclipse Link didn't see them.

Comment: Great .... but no error, no warning ... strange

Comment: Exactly what I thought. I expected to see some pop-up or warning in some way. By the way no problem, I finally got it :D
Thank you the same!

Answer (score 0):

I've finally made it.

I forgot to insert hibernate dependencies in my pom.xml. Once done I configured an Hibernate Console and tried again.

Now all works fine, I missed the most important point...